# Does "Could I have hope of getting admission of your school with that score?" sound weird?

Tags: letter-writing

Does "Could I have hope of getting admission of your school with that score?" sound weird?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the grammar, but for the fact that 'of' should read 'to'. One gets, or (better still) gains admission 'to' an establishment. (Though once you are in, you become part 'of' the place.) However, the sentence is excessively 'wordy'. 'Getting' is unnecessary. 'Would' might work better than 'could', but the meaning changes very slightly. Consider one of the following:

'Could there be any hope for my admission to your school, with that score?'

'Would I have a hope of admission to your school, with that score?'

or my favoured alternative:

'Could I have a hope of admission to your school, with that score?'

Comment: Or, one could eschew could/would entirely: _Is there any hope of being admitted into your school with that score?_

Comment: There is nothing wrong with '... getting admission of your school ...'?

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth Quite right. I do apologise. There is a glaring grammatical deficit, and have amended my answer accordingly.

Comment: But _could I have hope_ is not idiomatic. When we talking about hoping for a particular outcome, _hope_ is usually a count noun, so _could I have a hope_ (which you mentioned but didn't explain the emendation).

Comment: @Colin Fine. Yes, you are right, but as I think you recognise in your comment when you say 'usually', 'hope' without the article, just about scrapes home as being grammatical! Though 'Does she have hope of success?' contains ambiguity, whilst with the article the meaning is clear. Without, it could mean 'is she hoping for success?' or 'is there any hope of success?'

Comment: @Colin Fine. Grammatical without being idiomatic, is how I might describe that part of the OP's sentence. I should have said that in my answer. It is not actually ungrammatical to say 'Could I have  hope of getting admission...?

Comment: @Colin: That sounds rather dogmatic. There is yet hope for this question, or at least some hope.

Comment: @TimLymington: I did hedge it with "usually" ;-). But your example is not to the point: there is no particular outcome in "hope for the question"; in fact, I would argue that it is a different meaning of _hope_. I might reword my condition as "When _hope_ is (or might be) followed by _of_ or _that_, it is usually a count noun". Though it is a bit anomalous, I admit, because it can be qualified by _some_ or _any_, which count nouns usually can't, in that sense.

Comment: @Colin: We may have to conclude that 'usually' depends on your viewpoint and experiences ("for hope of heaven or fear of hell"). But for the record, my own belief is that *hope* is usually a mass noun: *there is (some) hope that he'll recover* sounds more natural to me than *there is a hope...*

Comment: Yes, I concede that last point. And my concession about _some_ and _any_ also weakens my statement. I'm now coming to think that there are two meanings of _hope_, one of which is count and the other mass (like _thought_), and there are some contexts where either will fit, but other contexts where only one will.